# How to get objects related to symfony validation errors

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I have an Entity on which I perform validation before save in my controller.

```
/** @var ConstraintViolationList $errors */
    $errors = $this->validator->validate($entity);
```

So when validation fails I'm getting list of `ConstraintViolation` objects.
How can I retrieve the related objects for those errors? My goal is to return mapped errors to each entity (this will highlight invalid elements in frontend side).

I will use custom field from object instead of id - all objects have it before saving to db, so frontend could distinguish them.
I suppose that I should write my own constraint normalizer but it doesn't know anything about related objects for errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ConstraintViolationList` behaves like an iterator of `ConstraintViolationInterface` implementation. From each `ConstraintViolationInterface` object, you can call `getPropertyPath` method that gives you the property path to the invalid element of root data (root data may be retrieved with `getRoot` method from any `ConstraintViolationInterface` implementation.

```
use Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccess;

// ...

foreach ($errors as $error) {
    $invalidElementAccessor = PropertyAccess::createPropertyAccessor();
    $invalidElement = $invalidElementAccessor->getValue($error->getRoot(), $error->getPropertyPath());

    // Do something with element
}
```

Comment: I have skipped some detalization on my problem but this also helped me, thanks! I'm working with relation, it has a property with collection. So when I validate parent entity (not each entity in related collection) I can't separate them by violations. I did it another way - validated each entity in collection and filled ViolationList object. After that I added custom constraint normalizer and got my properties from those violations